# Input data into remix through javascript

Tags: remix, nodejs

I am trying to update and call data to remix using node js. I have the temperature captured in my js code and I am trying to call it using the updateWeather function.

Node.js code

```
let request = require('request');
let url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item.condition%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20%3D%202487889&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys'

request(url, function (err, response, body) {
  if(err){
    console.log('error:', error);
  } else {
    let weather = JSON.parse(body)
    let temperature = weather.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp.toString();
    let message = `It's ${temperature} in Hawaii!`;
    console.log(message);
  }
});

Web3 = require('web3')
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    }

    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

const contract = web3.eth.contract(ABI).at('ADDRESS');

const account = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.eth.getAccounts((err, accounts) => {
      if (err === null) {
        resolve(accounts[0]);
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
};

const updateWeather = ({temperature }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    account().then(account => {
      contract.updateWeather(temperature,{ from: account }, (err, res) => {
          if (err === null) {
            resolve(res);
          } else {
            reject(err);
          }
        }
      );
    }).catch(error => reject(error));
  });
};

const weatherUpdate = (callback) => {
  contract.WeatherUpdate((error, result) => callback(error, result));
};
```

Remix Code

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;


contract WeatherOracle {

  event WeatherUpdate (
    string temperature
  );

  function updateWeather (string temperature) public {
      emit WeatherUpdate (
      temperature
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe a problem, if you have any?

Comment: The problem is that I cant send my temperature value to my remix contract

Comment: Why do you have 2 methods to get accounts? `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];` and `const account = ()`?

Comment: Have you checked that you got the right address here `web3.eth.contract(ABI).at('ADDRESS');`? Have you tried `web3.eth.getCode('ADDRESS')`?

Comment: I don't know what is this syntax `contract.WeatherUpdate((error, result) =>`.

Comment: I do not see how this `const updateWeather = ({temperature }) => ` is getting the temperature.